# Attach to executable with Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What I'd really like to do is debug an executable using the Visual Studio debugger. It comes with an Attach to Process feature. Unfortunately, the target executable only lasts for a short period- much too short for me to launch the executable and then navigate through Visual Studio and attach to it. How can I command Visual Studio to launch the executable and immediately attach the debugger?

Comment: If you have control over the executable, you can program a pause into the application, say with `Console.ReadLine` or `Threading.Thread.Sleep(millis)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set breakpoint at the very beginning of a programm execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513654/how-to-set-breakpoint-at-the-very-beginning-of-a-programm-execution)

Comment: @Hans: Not a dupe at all, as I don't really care where the program is stopped prior to exit. Nor do I have source or anything of the target executable.

Comment: Mysterious.  What's the point of debugging then?

Comment: Which is what the linked solution will do.  Hard to guess why you can't make it work.

Comment: @Hans: I never said that it wouldn't, I only said that the two problems are not identical. The other guy had some extremely specific requirements that are not shared.

Answer (score 2):

[AttachToLazy](http://lazy.codeplex.com/) VS add-in can wait for a process to start and then attach to it.

This add-in was written for VS2008 and it looks like some people were able to get it to work with 2010 by adjusting some of the properties (info under the Discussions tab).