# can we attach a process to VS programatically as soon as the process is created?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-2008, process, pid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set breakpoint at the very beginning of program execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513654/how-to-set-breakpoint-at-the-very-beginning-of-program-execution)

I have an application in C. I am using VS 2008 for the development. I need to debug the C code by attaching the process with the Visual Studio. In normal conditions, the process can be simply attached, but here it is a bit tricky.

Following is the scenario:

The problem is that application gives some unwanted messages as soon as the application is run, i.e. PROCESS is created. The time is too small to get the PID and attach it to the VS.

My question now is:

Can we do something( write some program or there is some workaround) so that we can attach the process as soon as it is created?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Abhishek Anand

Comment: This is not the same question as "How t oset breakpoint at the very beginning of program execution". That question is how to set a breakpoint a Create Process, while this is just a basic "How do I automatically attach a debugger when my target application starts?" The difference is that the user is asking a basic normal debugging question and it has several answers to it. This user doesn't specify before all the standard dlls load. The other question is a particular corner case of debugging, and it has a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so is to set a break point in the start of your source code, and use the Visual Studio to start debugging the application. You can use F5 or Debug|Start Debugging menu item to do this.

If you have to wait for another process to start your erroring program, then download and install "Debugging Tools For Windows" if you have not already got it. It can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

It is free debugging tools from Microsoft for debugging on all supported Windows OS.

It includes an utility called GFlags. Use GFlags to set the automatic debug options on your target program. This is the easiest way to set your system to start a debugger that will automatically be started up when the target application starts. I prefer to use WinDbg.exe (it is included in the tools package), but you can have Visual Studio start up as your debugger if you prefer.

The link above includes links for Debugging help.