# RPC Debugging in VS 2012

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com

Using [How to: Debug COM Clients and Servers Using RPC Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf71skzd.aspx) as a reference, I was trying to automatically attach and Debug a COM Server Component while initiating the COM Client Component. The COM Server DLL is hosted inside a surrogate Process. Per the mentioned linked documentation I was expecting to see something called a native page

> To enable RPC debugging
>
> ```
>     On the Tools menu, click Options.
>     In the Options dialog box, click the Debugging folder.
>     Click the Native page.
>     Select the RPC debugging check box.
> ```

But in the Options Page in VS 2012 (Premium) I cannot see any such Native Page from where I can enable RPC debugging
[image]

Any Idea how can I enable RPC debugging from VS2012?

The General procedure I am following is a bit naive

1. I start the client process in the debugger
2. Once I am pass through COCreateInstance I keep a note of dllhost process in Task Manager (Note I am running the COM through a Surrogate)
3. Now from Task Manager, I attach a debugger and then continue debugging the Server Process

Comment: There used to be a property page titled "Native" under the Debugging node.  It is not there anymore, removed in VS2012.  Which is okay, I never got it to work once.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am current following the process I have updated in my answer to Debug a COM Server Process. Is there a recommended Process that you would like to suggest for VS2012?

Comment: What you're doing is fine.  You could also invoke the jit debugger by using __debugbreak() in the server code.  I often use [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513654/how-to-set-breakpoint-at-the-very-beginning-of-program-execution/5514248#5514248).

Comment: I was wondering if I need glasses since MSDN still mentions this in an article updated in 2018. But I suppose I wasn't the only one who couldn't find this option in VS2017 anymore.