# What is the equivalent of System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() in unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging

I need to launch a debugger from my native C++ program when certain conditions are met. In C# I just call System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(). I thought that Win32 DebugBreak() call will do what I want, but it just terminates the application if there is no debugger present.

How do I launch a new instance of the debugger (the famous "Possible debuggers" dialog) from native code? Is it even possible? I could try to use COM to create a new instance of Visual Studio, but it is kinda complicated, and will also lock me to a particular version of VS.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and also found no solution.  I finally solved my problem by putting the call to System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch in a mixed-mode DLL, export the function as an unmanaged function, and then explicitly load the library using LoadLibrary from my unmanaged application.

Comment: This is cool, but not when your application hosts the CLR. Loading a managed library kinda messes up the whole hosting thing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I turns out that it is possible to call vsjitdebugger.exe directly with the PID of the current process. Make sure that "Native" is selected in Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-in-Time in Visual Studio.

Here's C++ code to launch debugger. It uses UNICODE versions of various Win32 APIs. I get System directory, because CreateProcess() does not use PATH.

```
bool launchDebugger()
{
    // Get System directory, typically c:\windows\system32
    std::wstring systemDir(MAX_PATH+1, '\0');
    UINT nChars = GetSystemDirectoryW(&systemDir[0], systemDir.length());
    if (nChars == 0) return false; // failed to get system directory
    systemDir.resize(nChars);

    // Get process ID and create the command line
    DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    std::wostringstream s;
    s << systemDir << L"\\vsjitdebugger.exe -p " << pid;
    std::wstring cmdLine = s.str();

    // Start debugger process
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, &cmdLine[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) return false;

    // Close debugger process handles to eliminate resource leak
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    // Wait for the debugger to attach
    while (!IsDebuggerPresent()) Sleep(100);

    // Stop execution so the debugger can take over
    DebugBreak();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I needed to debug an out-of-process COM server.

Comment: I'm currently attempting to host CoreCLR inside a managed application and I've found this is the only way to get mixed debugging working. Starting with mixed debugging from VS causes debugger crashes, calling just DebugBreak causes deadlock, as does `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch`.

Comment: After a long period of struggeling this saved me. I also had to set "Native" in the debugger settings, and working dir and output to the app that created the process (via QProcess).

Comment: Nice! I guess there is no good way to not wait forever when the user clicks "cancel" on the vsjitdebugger dialog? Without introducing a race for the debugger to be attached. I guess the best we can do is to wait for the process to exit and then wait a bit (timeout 1minute for example) if a debugger attaches itself?

Comment: To answer my last comment: You can wait for the process to exit with exit-code 0 and then wait for the debugger to attach. I couldn't find any docs for this but from testing the exit code is 262320 when the user clicks Cancel or the X for closing the dialog.

Comment: @matthid: cool, I had no idea about that exit code. Thanks for the research! I also did not know the process actually exits: I thought one can continue running it under the debugger.

Answer (score 11):

DebugBreak() is fine, so is the __debugbreak() intrinsic.  They both do the same thing, they crash the program with a STATUS_BREAKPOINT exception.  Which then triggers the Windows Error Reporting dialog, it trundles for a while then offers the Debug button.  Which then starts the debugger.

The only real mistake you could make is not waiting long enough for the WER dialog and pressing Cancel too quick.  Or having WER disabled.  If there is no debugger available at all then, yes, you don't get to choose one.

The registry key that matters is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger.  Normally set to vsjitdebugger.exe, the one that displays the "Possible debuggers" dialog.

Comment: Nope. DebugBreak() causes the error dialog "foobar.exe stopped working, Windows is checking for a solution to the problem". At no point I am offered to choose a debugger. At least this is what happens on Windows 7.

Comment: That's the WER dialog I mentioned.  Tap your foot and don't click Cancel.  And check that registry key.

Comment: Indeed, if you wait for a while and then click "debug" you get to choose a debugger. Should have been more patient. However, System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() gets to the debugger choice dialog right away, without a 45-second wait. Another complication is that my application does not get invoked directly by the user. If it did, I would not need tricks to attach debugger to it. If I use DebugBreak(), the parent application seems to think that the child process just has died and bails on me, but I did not investigate that deeply yet.

Comment: Sigh, why do you omit these important details from your question?  Use [this approach instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5514248/17034).

Comment: Thanks. I know about this one. Another important detail :) is that multiple processes with the same name are started. I don't want to debug all of them, I need to launch the debugger only when certain conditions are met. I heard about a workaround that suggests to create a DLL with Image File Execution Options set, and load it when you need to launch a debugger. Having said all that, an ability to just launch the debugger choice dialog would be very helpful. After all, .NET somehow does it, so it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`_CrtDbgBreak()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k4wx2tde.aspx) from your Visual C++ code, recompile, run your program and then select *Debug the program* from the dialog.

[image]