# How to attach a process to a running "devenv.exe" from inside its own C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I would like to attach a process from inside its C++ code to an existing "devenv.exe" instance for debugging purpose (or launch one if none).

Is this possible ? I saw it is possible in C# so I guess there is some way to do that in C++ as well.

The best I can achieve this far is to run a VSJitDebugger.exe instance with a `system()` call, but this prompts a window to choose which instance to use for debugging. I'd like to have a silent attachment to the one I select direcly in the code.

Thanks

Comment: You can try to call vsjitdebugger.exe directly with the PID of the current process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337870/what-is-the-equivalent-of-system-diagnostics-debugger-launch-in-unmanaged-code, is it what you want to get?

Comment: I have already tried this and it is what I get this far. What I would like to achieve is to skip the "select the debugger" dialog displayed by VsJitDebugger, I would like to have the same "silent" behavior as If I were already attached to a debugger in fact, by selecting the devenv.exe I want.

Comment: would you mind sharing the document about how to achieve it in C#? My understanding is that the JIT debugging was used to captured the Exception out of the VS, we could disable it(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it would not call the JIT debugging, do you want to use the Process::Attach Method () without calling the JIT debugging?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I found it here : 
https://gist.github.com/atruskie/3813175

Comment: So you test it using the C# sample, it worked well, am I right? If so, the real issue that you want to use the same way with the VC++ custom code, like this link here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac5yxx6(v=vs.110).aspx, all methods which will  trigger the JIT-attach have the matched VC++ format. Not the VC++ expert, but my understanding, it would have the same feature as the C#.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I don't find these functions in the Windows API. Is it managed C++ ? Because It seems so... and if so I don't want to use managed C++ in my code. My last solution is to create a C# sharp program which do that simple job and call that program from my C++...

Comment: It would be the Managed code, but if you don't want to use it, I agree with you, use the C# to call your VC++ would be a better workaround.