# Debug .Net and C++ app

Tags: c++, .net, debugging

I got two apps, one is .Net and other one is C++. The C++ app launches the .Net(wpf) app from within.
I need to debug the .net app when the c++ app launches it.
So I did the following changes:
**1.** I mentioned c++ exe in" Start External program" in debug properties of the .net app.
**2.** Also checked Enable Native Debugging option.
Now when i start .Net app then it launches the c++ app but it does not break in .Net app when it should because the breakpoint are disable due to the reason " symbols are not loaded".

Can you please help with it?
Saurabh

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to manually attach the debugger to the child process. I've only ever used mixed mode debugging and "start external program" for dlls. Visual studio version?

Comment: VS 2013 is the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, the debugger does *not* automatically debug a started child process.  Workarounds:

- Use Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the running WPF program
- If debugging the startup of the WPF program is important then temporarily add a `Debugger.Break()` call in the App class constructor.
- If modifying the WPF program is not practical then use the `Image File Execution Options` registry key to automatically launch a debugger whenever the WPF program is started.  Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514248/17034) for details.
- If the C++ code only passes command line arguments but does not otherwise interop with the WPF program then you can debug just the WPF app, use Project + Properties, Debug tab to set those command line options.
- If it is not critical that the WPF app gets started by the C++ app, but just needs to be running, then you can configure the Solution settings and ask for both programs to be started.  Right-click it, Startup Project, select the "Multiple" radio button.