# How to run executable via VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, process, executable

I have bugous compiled executable and I want to attach application to VS2013, but exe caught fatal error before I clicked on button "attach" in Studio, so I can't view call stack.
Are there ways to run application via Studio 2013 with attachment immediatly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5514248/17034