# How to debug .exe file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a big C# solution and I'm calling a certain project (application) via `Process` class by passing the path to the project I want to run. It works, but I can't debug it (it's in the same solution so I should be able to do that). What can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514248/17034

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this article by Microsoft: "[Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022).

*"You can attach the Visual Studio debugger to a running process on a local or remote computer. After the process is running, select Debug > Attach to Process or press Ctrl+Alt+p in Visual Studio, and use the Attach to Process dialog to attach the debugger to the process."*

Comment: Thanks but how can I stop this process until I attach debugger to it? Because it takes some time until I attach it :(

Comment: Using a breakpoint, maybe?